# Translating this nested quantifier to english (negation of nested quantifiers)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

So i'm a total newb at this so I need help on one the questions for my assignment:

Let S(x) = “x is a student at Bronx Community College”; F(x) = “x is a faculty member at Bronx Community College”, and E(x,y) “x has eaten y at the Bronx Community College cafeteria” where the universe of discourse for x is all the people who are associated with Bronx Community College, and the universe for discourse for y is the menu items in the Bronx Community College cafeteria

translate this to english:

```
∃x¬∃y(F(x)⟹ E(x,y))
```

i'm probably messing this up or something I just can't get the right words from this except the other half " a faculty member at bronx cc that has eaten at the bronx cc cafeteria "

Comment: Put yourself "in the shoes" of $x$.  What would the proposition say about you?

Comment: hmm ;_;   "There is someone who has not seen the menu items in bronx cc is a faculty member at Bronx cc that has eaten  at bronx cc cafeteria?

Comment: I'm suggesting we un-nest the quantifiers a bit, by having you take the role of $x$, which is bound as outer existential quantifier.  This reduces the clutter to interpreting `¬∃y(F(x)⟹ E(x,y))`.  Also see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for introductory notes on how to post mathematical expressions typeset with $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited: It would be something like "there is some faculty member at BCC that hasn't eaten anything at the BCC cafeteria".
You can think it this way:
$\exists x \lnot \exists y (F(x) \implies E(x,y))$ is equivalent to $\exists x \forall y \lnot(F(x) \implies E(x,y))$ which is equivalent to $\exists x \forall y (F(x) \land \lnot E(x,y))$ and finally this is equivalent to $\exists x (F(x) \land \forall y \lnot E(x,y))$. The last equivalence holds because you can always "split" a formula like $\forall y (\alpha \land \beta)$ into $\forall y \alpha \land \forall y \beta$, in addition if you have something like $\forall y \alpha$ it is equivalent to $\alpha$ if the variable $y$ is not in $\alpha$

Comment: it's : existential quantification of x , negation of  existential quantification of y , where f(x) "x is a faculty member at bcc" implies that E(x,y) "x has eaten y at the BCC cafeteria  . where the u.d for x is all the people who are associated with BCC and the u.d for y is the menu items in the Bronx Community College cafeteria

Comment: Ok, let me correct it then, just give me one moment

Comment: thanks ! and thank you for clarifying the equivalents for my symbols ;_; !